How to deploy a Teams-Toolkit app that uses an external API to a client?
I am using Visual Studio 2022 Version 17.12.3 with the Teams Toolkit.
I used the "Chat With Your Data" template and selected Azure OpenAI, as we are Azure OpenAI customers.
Then I changed the RenderDataAsync() method to call an external API that I have built and return the output to Teams:
public async Task<RenderedPromptSection<string>> RenderDataAsync(ITurnContext context, IMemory memory, ITokenizer tokenizer, int maxTokens, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    string? query = memory.GetValue("temp.input") as string;

    if (query == null)
    {
        return new RenderedPromptSection<string>(string.Empty, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var requestUri = "http://<domain-name>/query";
        var requestBody = new
        {
            query = query,
            mode = "local"
        };

        var json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(requestBody);
        var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, requestUri)
        {
            Headers =
            {
                { "accept", "application/json" }
            },
            Content = content
        };
        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var answer = responseContent;
        return new RenderedPromptSection<string>(formatDocument(answer), answer.Length);
    }
}

This works without problem when I test it locally, I can also import the appPackage.dev.zip and publish the app to my Office-365-org and it just works as expected.
But what do I have to distribute to my client in a different Office-365-org? If I give him my appPackage.dev.zip he is able to install it but the bot never gets any response, I don't even see any requests being made to my API.
What am I missing?
I gave the customer the appPackage.dev.zip, he installed it in his own Office-365-org, I was expecting the same behaviour as in my own org, but it failed.

Thanks for your question.
After our test, the latest template bot works fine in multiple orgs.
Maybe you can check it in following steps.

Please make sure you use the latest version.
Since the bot works fine in your organization, it seems the problem occurs in the different org. You can watch the Azure bot traffic in the Azure bot->Monitoring->Metrics, and select the Request Traffic to watch his traffic arrives or not.


In addition, you can raise bug in https://github.com/OfficeDev/teams-toolkit/issues.
